# Calling a "for" loop twice to print two receipts

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth printer integrated to my app and if I do some transactions, I can print the receipt to the customer. I have a method to handle the printing of receipts. Currently, I can print only one receipt but I would like to print the receipts twice.

Should I run the `for` loop twice so the method which prints my receipt is executed twice.

```
private void printReceipt(final Transaction transaction) {
    showProgressPopup(getString(R.string.printing_dialog_message));
    Runnable printThread = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final BitSet resultBit = new BitSet(1);
            try {
                final ReceiptMetadata receiptMetadata =
                        AirFiUtils.getPaymentDeviceReceiptMetaData(getAirlineProfile(),
                                AirFiUtils.getMerchantAccount(getAirFiActivity()));
                if (null != receiptMetadata) {
                    PrinterManager.printReceipt(PrinterType.valueOf(receiptMetadata.getPrinter().get(0)),
                            ReceiptType.CASH, receiptMetadata, transaction, getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            transaction.isSignatureCard());

                    resultBit.set(0, true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error in printing ", e);
                resultBit.set(0, false);
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(printThread).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use for loop inside your if statement e.g

```
if(your_condition){
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
//your desired code to print receipt
}}
```

or call your specific function two time which is need to be print receipt by applying for loop